# Mimic MouseIn/Out

Tags: vb.net, mouseevent, mouseout

I am trying to hide my cursor when a user enters a button, and show it when they leave the button.

So far I am using the `MouseEnter` and `MouseLeave` Events

```
Private Sub btnbeis_MouseEnter(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnBeis.MouseEnter
   Dim btn As Button = DirectCast(sender, Button)
   btn.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat
   Cursor.Hide()
End Sub

Private Sub btnbeis_mouseLeave(sender As System.Object, e as system.EventArgs) Handles btnbeis.MouseLeave
    Dim btn As Button = DirectCast(sender, Button)
    btn.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Standard
    cursor.Show()
End Sub
```

However because MouseEnter is hit every time the user moves the mouse, it keeps on hiding the mouse

I found the MouseOut event but it does not work for vb, is there anything that mimics mouseout?
Meaning I only want it to hit when the mouse leave the button, and enters for the first time

**EDIT**

I tried this on a new form and it works perfectly

But on this form it keeps on hitting the mouseEnter and MouseLeave, when I debug it keeps on going from mouseEnter to MouseLeave and back to MouseEnter

I Do Not have any code under mouseMove, so that is not the problem

Thank You!

Comment: Typo on the Handles clause?

Comment: Sorry, just my typing mistake, It is hitting it, every time i move the mouse, not just when it enters the button or leaves the button

Comment: winforms or what?  MouseOut is not a winforms event

Comment: @Plutonix I'm using Winforms, and that is my question, is there anything that mimics MouseOut?

Comment: you have something else wrong in your code then.  MouseEnter and MouseLeave work as you would expect.  Look at the code in MouseMove

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Button1MouseLeave(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Cursor.Show()
End Sub

Sub Button1MouseEnter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Cursor.Hide()
End Sub
```

Comment: What is the problem with that code? You want to hide the cursor when it's over the button and show it again when it leaves the button?

Comment: Yes, but the way Cursor.Hide() works is that if there it hits cursor.Hide twice it will need two cursor.show() to show, everytime i move the mouse it "saves up" a cursor.hide(). I only want it to hide if it is entering the button for the first time

Comment: How are you testing your code? Do you have any more code on that form? If so, have you tried with a new blank form? There isn't anything like a "show/hide" stack; the event is fired everytime the mouse enters the button, that's completely normal, but that doesn't mean it "re-hides" the cursor everytime is fired.

Comment: You are correct that there has to be a corresponding show with a hide.  According to MSDN the enter should fire when you enter and not when you're moving around over and over.  I successfully used their example and it works:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.cursor.hide(v=vs.110).aspx